# Dynamic controls are not going away

Tags: asp.net

I have an existing application page that's fairly large. I have to add some content to it that's dynamic. I want to add the content on a button click. This is currently not working. Owell...

However, if I generate the content on page init or load during a non postback event the content does generate. Great!

What's weird is that when I initiate the postback and don't regenerate the content, upon the page completing it's load, the dynamic content is still there!!!

Because the content is being generated dynamically I'd expect it to be gone after a postback. Is there an asp setting that I'm unaware of that might account for why the dynamic content doesn't go away on postback? Is there a non asp standard that might account for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you suggesting view state is responsible for the regeneration of the dynamic controls? I thought it was responsible for population of control attributes on content only if it existed on the pages list of controls.

Answer (score 0):

So in my case, the reason this wasn't working as expected is because the page was using UpdatePanels. Thus when a post back occurred only the areas w/ an update panel updated as expected.

I needed to put the placeholder I was populating into an UpdatePanel. Now the content generates as expected.